# Assumptions for Definite Integral of Log[]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I have a given function:

```
sol = t D[ri t/(v - b) - (1/v - 1/(v + b)) a/(b Sqrt[t]), t] // FullSimplify
```

I now need to integrate this function across $v$ within a specific region v1, v2 (which means a relatively 'simple' definite integral of $\int\frac{1}{v}dv$ which would be a $\log_e\frac{v2}{v1}$ kind of solution.

```
Integrate[sol, {v, v1, v2}]
```

However try as I might, it seems that MMA cannot quickly/easily solve this integral. My assumption is, that this has problems in the symbolic solution because of (un)specific constraints, so to reduce the work, I tried.

```
Integrate[sol,{v,v1,v2}, Assumptions -> {v \[Element] Reals, v1 > 0, v2 > 0}]
```

However this can't be solved either and try as I can to google or check the documentation I can't seem to find how one would get to the correct solution. For relatively 'simple' equations like this, I can easily solve this by hand...or well 'memory' However I have ever increasingly difficult systems to work with and I would like to calculate these kind of integrals.

How does one do definite integrals of 1/x functions to get the expected symbolic solution of Log[x2/x1]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems are related to the fact that the integral has several parameters. Depending on their values the integral may exist, or not.

Let us see.

This is your function

```
sol=(ri t)/(-b + v) + a/(Sqrt[t] (2 b v + 2 v^2));
```

Let us solve first an undetermined integral, calculating the terms of your function separately:

```
Integrate[#, v, Assumptions -> {ri > 0, t > 0, b > 0}] & /@ sol

(*  ri t Log[-b + v] + (a (Log[v]/(2 b) - Log[b + v]/(2 b)))/Sqrt[t]   *)
```

Now, one can see that in order for the integral to exist one should require `v-b>0` `v+b>0` and `t!=0`. Besides, it is useful to define that `v1>0` and `v2>v1`. Of course, if the integration along the real axis corresponds to your intention. With this

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Integrate[sol, {v, v1, v2}, 
  Assumptions -> {ri > 0, t > 0, b > 0, v1 > 0, v2 > v1, v1 > b}]]
```

in 0.6s yields the result:

```
(*  {0.619135, 
 ri t Log[(b - v2)/(b - v1)] + (a Log[((b + v1) v2)/(v1 (b + v2))])/(
  2 b Sqrt[t])}  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

You can immediately get an answer to the indefinite integral:

```
Integrate[sol, v]

(* Out: (a Log[v] + 2 b ri t^(3/2) Log[-b + v] - a Log[b + v])/(2 b Sqrt[t]) *)
```

The definite integral churns for a long time without success without assumptions, as you saw. However, if you add assumptions that all parameters are real, and that $v2>v1>0$, you can get an answer as a `ConditionalExpression`:

```
Integrate[
  sol, {v, v1, v2}, 
  Assumptions -> {{t, ri, b, a} ∈ Reals, v2 > v1 > 0}
]

(* Out: 
ConditionalExpression[
  ri t Log[(b - v2)/(b - v1)] + (a Log[((b + v1) v2)/(v1 (b + v2))])/(2 b Sqrt[t]),
  b < v1 && b + v1 > 0
]
*)
```